# Angular Material sidebar is above content instead of pushing main container when adding content dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-material

When I add content to the navbar dynamically, e.g. async with a http call, then it has wrong sizes when setting `[opened]="true"`

See: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ayttch?file=app%2Fsidenav-mode-example.html)

[image]

The navbar is overlaying the `content`. I would expect however to have this (as will be when toggeling the navbar)

[image]

When toggeling, the size is correct.. how can I make it have correct sizes after adding content to the navbar?

Comment: Your SlackBlitz doesn't include a replication of your issue. I've tested it by using a button to add new text and the sidebar expands as expected. What seems to be the issue with this?

Comment: I see it might be slightly confusing, I added some screenshots, hope it make things clearer

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution, see this issue on github

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9782

on could use `autosize`

Hope, this helps others as well.

**Old**

I have found a solution, but it is terrible from a coding point of view

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.myText = "My long text";
  this.matSidenav.toggle();
  this.matSidenav.toggle(); }, 1500);
}
```

What this does is basically after the content was loaded I just toggle the sidebar twice and everything is as expected.

Is this a bug?